# Best way to minimize the ubuntu base image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, minimization

I am trying to minimize the ubuntu base image for networking tools.

Till now I have been looking at the whole file system to remove the files that are not needed.
This is a very tedious process and I am not sure if I will get the results or not.

Can anyone suggest a better path to go on about this.

Comment: Why not to use other base image which is smaller e.g. `alpine` or debian `-slim`?

Comment: The way Docker works internally, you can never make an image smaller: you'll get the `ubuntu` base image, plus also (delete these files), which is the same size.  In addition to the base images @KarolDowbecki suggests, if you're very brave you can run a custom distribution install on `scratch`...but you have to know which parts specifically you need to install.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you will have an easier time using a Debian `-slim` image. However, you can use the tool that Debian uses to build its Docker images, [`debuerreotype`](https://github.com/debuerreotype/debuerreotype), to build Ubuntu images as well, using the `ubuntu.sh` script. There is a `-slim` variant produced by that tool, which may work for your needs.